# Reordering of code around synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm considering writing a singleton framework that looks something like this:

```
Object getSingleton(name) {
    synchronized(A)
    {
        o = A.get(name)
        if (o != null)
        {
            while ( ! A.isInitialized(name) )
            {
                A.wait()
            }
            return o;
        }

        o = new Thing();
        A.put(o)
        A.setInitialized(name, false)
    }

    o.init()

    synchronized(A)
    {
        A.setInitialized(name, true)
        A.notifyAll()
    }

    return o;
}
```

The point is to allow o.init() to interact with other threads that may want to call getSingleton() and not cause a deadlock on A.

Will this work the way I want, or is it possible for o.init() to be reordered relative to the synchronization blocks? Or is there an entirely better way to do this?

Comment: just forget about using singletons; they are super contentious and as many say they are terrible as say the are awsome.  Just use a dependancy injection framework (for example, Spring) to handle your singletons.  Fyi Spring singletons are "effectively" singletons.

Comment: Actually for most cases I find using simply *eager* initialization much simpler and it can often make all synchronization superflous.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache.org's [`LazyInitializer` class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html), it sounds like all you need.

Comment: I think OP actually wants to learn something here, not just get a working singleton with lazy initialization

Comment: @JanDvorak that's fine.  OP can also learn there's a standard class that does this already, in addition to learning something else.